# What Permission to view a user's own Profile/Dashboard

Tags: permissions

What permission must I grant to a user so that he can view his dashboard (/civicrm/user?reset=1) ?

(Currently running Civi 4.7.27 / Drupal 7.59)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Dashboard & Permissions

If you want to give the user ability to see information on themself, the permission seems to be `CiviCRM: access Contact Dashboard`. (I expected `CiviCRM: view my contact` to be a requirement also, but it doesn't seem to be necessary for a contact to view their own dashboard.)

If you also want to give the ability to edit the logged in user via the contact dashboard, the permission is `CiviCRM: edit my contact`.

Permission to access to other CiviCRM components may dictate which Dashboard elements appear on the user's dashboard.

Here's [CiviCRM's documentation on permissions](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/).

Comment: If you're using Drupal, you can also configure the Drupal user edit screen to include specific CiviCRM profiles/fields for the user to self manage (check `View/Edit Drupal User Account` in the Profile's settings), *and* you have the option of [Webform](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/webform/#compared-to-civicrm-profiles) as well.

Comment: Sorry, but even with Civicrm : edit my contact permission, access is still denied. I edit my question to show a creen shot of what I want (Profiles is not a solution for me)

Comment: I tested this locally on CiviCRM 5.2 and have updated the answer!

Comment: Hi Chris, hi Pete, I don't want to tune or control the display (I know how to do that, using Views or Profiles) ; I just want an authenticated user to be allowed to display his dashboard (which I can do as an admin : see my screen-shot) ; neither VIEW MY CONTACT nor EDIT MY CONTACT permissions enable that, so what permission must I grant ?

Comment: Hi Jacques, the answer above recommends permission `CiviCRM: access Contact Dashboard` in the first paragraph. (I'm surprised that you don't *also* need `CiviCRM: view my contact`, but that was what I found when testing locally with CiviCRM 5.2.)

Comment: Oups Chris ; I apologize I must have misread your answer : it's OK now. Thanks a lot. (By the way, "View my contact" and "Edit my contact" are not necessary permissions).

Comment: That's ok, I'd edited the (originally incorrect) answer. Kia ora for confirming the other perms aren't required!

Answer (score 3):

### Consider Profiles

Another common method for exposing a limited set of fields for users to self-manage is a **Profile**, allows contacts to edit specific fields only. Advantages of Profiles include:

- Not all CRM data is directly visible or editable to the contact, so Profiles can allow limited editing functionality to ensure organisational data integrity.
- Profiles can be accessible to contacts who do not have a CMS user account - many sites don't have matching (CMS) User accounts for all their (CRM) Contact records.

See the documentation on [CiviCRM Profiles](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/) for more details, and [Initial Setup → Customising the user interface](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/customizing-the-user-interface/#making-custom-data-entry-forms) also.

Answer (score 3):

### ... and then there is Views

if you really want to fine tune what the user can 'see' then either directing them to a drupal path with various Views Blocks, or adding those Views Blocks to show on the Dashboard page can help.

If you also want the user to be able to modify 'some' data about themselves, then linking from the Views Block to a webform with ?cid1=[id] can usually take a user to a prefilled Webform where you can finely control what they see and what they can edit.